# Android Studio - Which view element for picking a height?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

at the moment im coding an android application.
There I need some different pickers.
For example a date picker to get a date of birth.
Also I will use the spinner to select from some text values.

But what view should I use for selecting from a big amount of text(number) values. For example the body height or weight?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Your question is not relates please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for the height, you can use spinner, and for the weight, you have to use `EditText` with `maxLength` = 2 or 3 and `inputType` = number